# Delete data from two tables

Tags: mysql, delete-row

I wish to delete data from two tables I have: **staff**, and **staff_take_courses**.
the SQLCommand line keeps giving the error:

```
ERROR 1451 (23000): Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`Exclusif`.`staff_take_courses`, CONSTRAINT `fk_staff_has_courses_staff1` FOREIGN KEY (`staff_id`) REFERENCES `staff` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION O
N UPDATE NO ACTION)
```

here is the query:

```
delete s, stc from staff s inner join staff_take_courses stc on stc.staff_id = s.id where s.id= '$id';
```

Comment: You have a foreign key constraint error, which means you also have to delete a corresponding record from another table.  And also your `delete` query looks strange.

Answer (score 2):

Why can you just delete in two statement:

```
 DELETE FROM staff_take_courses WHERE staff_take_courses.staff_id= '$id';
 DELETE FROM staff WHERE staff.id= '$id';
```

There must be a problem with the relationship between the tables. That are not allowing you to delete from the tables

Answer (score 1):

Delete from staff_take_courses where staff_take_courses.staff_id= '$id';
    Delete from staff WHERE staff.id= '$id';
    OR

```
Just use INNER JOIN as below

DELETE field1 , field2  FROM staff_take_courses  INNER JOIN staff  
WHERE staff_take_courses.staff_id= staff.id and staff_take_courses.staff_id = '1'
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot delete a table from database if that table have relationship with another table it will keep on giving you an error . Why not try to check your relationships?